# Extreme points of joint distributions of $(X,\hat X)$

Tags: probability-distributions, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Let $\mathcal X = \mathbb R^n$ and $\nu \in \mathcal P(\mathcal X)$ be a non-atomic Borel probability measure over $\mathcal X$ with finite second moment. Consider the following convex set,
$$
\mathcal S_\nu = 
\{\eta\in\mathcal P(\mathcal X\times\mathcal X), 
~(\mathrm{pr}_1)_*\eta = \nu,
~(\mathrm{pr}_2)_*((x-y)\eta) = 0
\},
$$
having noted $\mathrm{pr}_1(x,y) = x$, $\mathrm{pr}_2(x,y) = y$, and abusively $(x-y)\eta$ is the distribution defined by $(x-y)\mathrm d\eta(x,y)$. Essentially, $\eta\in\mathcal S_\nu$ if and only if $(X,Y)$ distributed according to $\eta$ are such that $X \sim\nu$ and $\mathbb E[X\mid Y] = Y$ (the estimate $\hat X$ of $X$ knowing $Y$, is $Y$).

My question is, how to characterize its extreme points?

So far, I found that when $\eta$ is constructed from $(X,Y)$ with $Y$ function of $X$, it is extreme. I also found that the converse holds if $(\mathrm{pr}_2)_*\eta$ has discrete support. However, I also have an example of $\eta$ extreme where $Y$ cannot be written as a function of $X$.

Comment: I'm really interested in your counterexample where $\eta$ is extreme but $Y$ is not a measurable function of $X$. I have a rough idea how to approach this problem, but unless there's an issue with my approach (which there probably is), the conclusion would be the same for continuous distributions as it is for discrete (the only extreme measures are the ones where $Y$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable).

Comment: You can consider $\nu$ to be the uniform probability over $[0,1]$. Let then $\mathbb P[.\mid X] = \alpha(X) \delta_{a(X)} + (1-\alpha(X)) \alpha(X) \delta_{b(X)}$ be the kernel, where $a,b\colon[0,1]\to[0,1]$ are two (smooth) bijections with $a(x)\geq x\geq b(x)$ and $\alpha\colon[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be measurable well-chosen so that $\mathbb E[X\mid Y] = Y$. I have a specific counterexample but the computation is just unnecessarily hairy.

Comment: Quick question, should that be $\mathbb{P}(\cdot|X) = \alpha(X) \delta_{a(X)} + (1 - \alpha(X))\delta_{b(X)}$ so that $\mathbb{P}([0,1]|X) = 1$?

Edit: Ok I see it now. That's a good counterexample and an interesting question. I'll keep thinking about it and reply if I figure anything out.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo I cannot edit unfortunately.